# How to sum all whole numbers from 0 to 1000

Tags: java, loops, class

**How to sum all whole numbers to 1000**

```
package proba;

public class Proba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int whole = 0;

        int n = 1000;
        int m = 500;
        while (a <= n) {
            if (a % 2 == 0) {
                whole += ;

            }
            a++;
            System.out.println("Rezultat parnih je: " + whole);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean all *even* numbers?

Comment: Considering the modulus `%`, more than likely

Comment: I need to sum all whole numbers from 0 to 1000, and then result of that i need to subtract with odd numbers from 1 to 500. Sorry for my bad post and etc. im new here and just need quick answer. Sorry.

Comment: This is called an arithmetic series. You can read more on Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Answer (score 1):

For all numbers from 0 till 1000, `for loop`

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

For all even numbers, use an `if` to see if they are even

```
if (i % 2 == 0) // remainder is 0, meaning even
    sum += i;
```

Edit: To add even and subtract odd

```
int sumOfEven;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        sumOfEven += i;
    }
}

int sumOfOdd;
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sumOfOdd += i;
    }
}
System.out.println(sumOfEven - sumOfOdd); // Math.absolute can also be done here for a non-negative value
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` should be `System.out.println`

Comment: No matter, i got it. But can you help me excatly with: I need to sum all whole numbers from 0 to 1000, and then result of that i need to subtract with odd numbers from 1 to 500.

Comment: Hey, code is good but i found on google that of sum 0 to 1000 is 250500 while i got 249500 ..

Comment: @FootballHighlight-Goals-News can you guess why? Hint, it has to do with the `if condition check`.

Comment: Please, stop kidding im, im new in this area, help me if you can, thanks.

Comment: That's why I want to help. The reason you are getting a lower value is because the `for loop` condition `i < 1000` and `i < 500` doesn't actually iterate the 500th loop. Therefore, the max `i` is equal to is either 999 or 499. To fix this, and get the values you'd like, change the conditional from `i < 1000` to `i <= 1000`. Same for the 500 one

Answer (score 0):

Adding all numbers just to subtract later 250 of them is not efficient. Just filter the ones you don't want in the total sum

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000)
                   .filter(i -> i >= 500 || i % 2 == 0)
                   .sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```